# Why do projects embed Newtonsoft into their namespace?

Tags: c#, json.net, ravendb

I have noticed this pattern in a few projects over the years, and most recently in RavenDB.

Opening Raven.Abstractions.dll in ILSpy, I noticed the ol "ProjectName.SomeScope.Newtonsoft"

[image]

Why is this done?? Looking at the source code in github, I'm guessing they are pulling in the source for Newtonsoft and using Foddy to weave the Newtonsoft types in to the Raven assembly.

I can only guess this is done to prevent type collisions: So Raven.Abstractions.Dll can have a specific version of Newtonsoft without imposing that you (as a consumer) also reference that version.

Any other thoughts?

Comment: R u using any convertor to converts?

Comment: They do it so you don't have to include another dependency on Newtonsoft.  That's it.  They aren't weaving anything.  Just packing assemblies together.  You can do this yourself fairly easily using ILMerge.  See https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/people/mbarnett/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason at the time was that it created a lot of conflicts with other projects that were using different and sometimes incompatible versions of json.net.
Having our own version meant we could avoid all of this.